# How thin should I print a logo so that it is flexible enough to wrap around a curved object?

Tags: layer-height

I want to print out a flat object without any support structure straight onto the build plate of my ender 5. It's going to be PLA and I need it to be thin enough to still be flexible.

I don't have a picture available, but imagine that I wanted to print out the Coke Cola and then wrap it around a bland soda can, so that the logo is raised up slightly?

Alternatively, what is the best layer height to use, and how many layers should I use?

Comment: This isn't an answer because you specified you want PLA, but TPU works really great for this at a thickness of around 1-2 mm and it's indestructible. You don't have to worry about bending it too sharply and creasing it, or about it being brittle from being so thin.

Comment: I'm _really_ new to 3D printing, so I'll ask a naive question: Why not just print it to the desired curve in the first place? Or, is flexibility the purpose, and the Coke can example was simply a way of saying it needed to be flexible?

Comment: @FreeMan printing flat negates the need for supports and is stronger and faster with zero chance of failure regardless of complexity. So you could print a 5cm high logo on it's edge with a curve, but that is 250 layers and if it was thin would be a problematic and brittle print. Or you could print it flat faster, stronger and cheaper.

Comment: @Kilisi thanks. As I said, possibly a naive question. That mostly makes sense.

Comment: @FreeMan You're welcome, we all have to start somewhere

Comment: For text such as the Coca Cola label consider a negative image, i.e. a thin, flat, rectangular piece with letter shaped holes.

Comment: This question makes little sense, each material is different. It takes very little time to print test samples and try. Do that.

Comment: @FarO the OP specified PLA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PLA you can just heat it to curve around the object. I've done this with up to 2mm. Real easy with 1mm.

I haven't tried thicker but assume it would work ok.

You'd have to glue it though to make it stick. My attempts were just to shape the prints, I didn't want them sticking so I shaped them around a glass bottle.

If you want it flexible in it's own right, then I suggest 2 * 0.2mm layers. I have a large 2 layer print in front of me that bends easily.

[image: 2 layers]

This can be rolled up into a tube, but as soon as you let go it will return to flat.

1 layer is even more flexible but tears along the lines with a bit of effort. So if you want it really flexible I suggest you print 1 layer at slightly lower than normal nozzle height to really get the lines melded together. Or a bit hotter than normal.

Comment: +1 for the heat reference. You'd be able to wrap something approaching 2-3 mm with enough heat. The thicker parts may experience some distortion. Leave a PLA part in a hot summer car and watch how much flexibility results!

Comment: @fred_dot_u Yeah, I've bent PLA around quite a bit for various reasons, usually to avoid layer line weakness or fasten things together. You can even make quite strong PLA rivets.

Comment: 2x 0.2 mm layers will flex very nicely, but will crease and crack if you bend them sharper than a certain limit.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE yes, they'll take quite a bit of abuse though, well within the parameters of the question. I use it often enough that I have a sheet lying around so I can cut pieces off it when I need to.

Answer (score 0):

**1 layer, of whatever thickness your device can print.**

I did something like this to print letters for a flat sign.  The letters were 1mm thick and didn't bend, but I'd accidentally printed quite a lot of brim lines which were a single layer thick, and they'd merged into each other.

The brim worked superbly as a "net" to hold the letters in place, so in theory you could print as little as one layer thick.

- Nozzle height will have to be exactly right to merge the lines together.  There are no lines crossing-over on the next layer to help bond them all together.
- Let the print bed cool to ambient before removing it from the bed, to help keep the lines connected.  Could take an hour or so.
- Use a wide flat scraper to pull job off bed - you might want to design in a "tab" that can be damaged while getting the tool started, and trimmed of later.